# How to create a Regular Expression with the following conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

Numerical input should not exceed 8 digits ( counting numbers on both the side of the decimal). Example: 123456.78 or 0.12 or 1.23

Numerical values should be able to accept negative numbers. Example: -0.8 , or -1.23

Max of 2 decimal number allowed

Numerical value should not accept any alpahbets in the input box

I tried Creating the following regular expression but i am not able to figure it out quite efficiently

```
^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?[,8]$
```

[**Regular exp**](https://regex101.com/r/rQMRVX/1/)

Comment: What is `[,8]` supposed to be? I think you mean `{,8}`, but it doesn't have any effect after `?`.

Comment: One way is to get rid of the `.`, split the numbers into an array, like `split("")`, and check the length. But I'm sure there is a better way

Comment: Yes @Barmar i am not able to max it out at 8 chars

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match the required number of digits and no more, lookahead at the beginning of the pattern for `(?:\d\.?)` 1 to 8 times, and then match `\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$` to match a number which, if containing decimals, contains at maximum 2 decimal characters:

```
^-?(?=(?:\d\.?){1,8}$)\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/rQMRVX/5

(unless you *need* to capture the decimal part, it can be a non-capturing group like above)

Comment: But it is not fixing the char at a max of 2 number after decimal

Comment: Sorry but i dont get this part `unless you need to capture the decimal part, it can be a non-capturing group like above)` Thanks for the help

Comment: That's...pretty good. I completely forgot you can do a lookahead as a "pre-filter" and then do the actual pattern matching.

Comment: @VLAZ `completely forgot you can do a lookahead as a "pre-filter" ` Sorry but can some one explain me how it worked out i dnt want to bother again with a regex will be a great learning

Comment: @INFOSYS It's best to only use capturing groups when you *need* to capture the group (and save it for later somehow, like in a backreference or use it to extract a substring). Otherwise, a non-capturing group is cheaper and easier to read (less cognitive overhead). A non-capturing group says "This is a group ONLY so that what it encases can be quantified".

Comment: @INFOSYS a caputring group is surrounded by `()` - it will capture any matches if finds and extract them separately. E.g., if you do `\d\(.\d)` you'd match two digits separated by a dot, but the dot and second digit will *also* be a separate entry in the output `"4.2".match(/\d\(.\d)/)` outputs `4.2` as the whole match and `.2` from the capture group. A non-capture group `(?:)` by comparison doesn't do this but it can be used to collect part of the pattern. You can use that to make the entire part optional without extracting an extra match `\d(?:\.\d)?`.

Comment: Thanks, also if you have some time to spare can you explain the regex what it does too will be a great learning for me and others starting with regex

Comment: @INFOSYS The lookahead for `(?:\d\.?){1,8}$` matches 8 digits, possibly interspersed with `.`s, ending at the end of the string. Then `\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$` matches any digits, possibly followed by `.` and one or two digits, followed by the end of the string.

Comment: @INFOSYS as the lookahead you can [read more about it here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Basically, you can check *ahead* in the string for some pattern before you actually continue matching. Lookaheads don't consume the input so you can use it to check if something broadly conforms before trying to match it. In this case the lookahead checks if the input only contains 8 digits and dots at most. This *would* allow for stuff like `1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.` but it will reject anything that has more than 8 digits. Then the rest of the regex will only match the input you want.

Comment: @VLAZ is there any possible way we can get to know why the regex failed , like for more chars after decimal or more chars in the sentence so that we need to do another validation again to get the correct error message

Comment: @CertainPerformance . is there any possible way we can get to know why the regex failed , like for more chars after decimal or more chars in the sentence so that we need to do another validation again to get the correct error message Sorry for bugging  both of you here

Comment: @INFOSYS If you like, you can make multiple separate regular expressions: one to check whether there are no more than 8 digits in the string, and one to check whether the decimal part contains 1-2 digits (if there is a decimal part at all), and maybe another to check whether the string is a properly formatted number (eg, at most one `-` at the beginning, and with only one `.` followed by digits, with `^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`). Then when a regex fails, you'll know why

Comment: @INFOSYS no, the regex engine will just try to match and stop if it cannot. E.g., if you have `^\d\.\d$` again but matching the entire string, then you cannot know if it failed because a) the input is empty string `""` b) the input only has a single digit `"4"` c) the input starts with a letter `"a.2"` d) there is no digit after the dot `"4.a"` or `"4."`, etc. The regex engine only says if the entire pattern matches or not. There are *some* that may supply extra output like where it failed but usually that's for debugging purposes and those aren't used in applications.

Comment: You can [test on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SdKCzR/1/debugger) via their regex debugger, though. This will show you how a regex engine will try to match something and if a regex fails, you can try this to see why. To use it - go to Regex101.com -> enter the regex in the top field -> enter the input in the field below -> go to the left-hand side menu -> select "Regex Debugger". This will show you how your regex works against the current input step by step.

Comment: So the only way is to split this up. now i am thinking of either spending some time learning regex or asking another question to split this up which is bad on my part

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
^-?\d{1,8}.?\d{1,2}$
```

Link : https://regex101.com/r/x7yw5M/2

Comment: This doesn't limit it to a maximum of 8 digits total.

Comment: @samanime just to give an example, this matches `12345678.12` which is ten digits total. It will also match `1234567890` since the dot is optional. Furthermore, it's not a *literal* dot, it's the regex dot as a wildcard `1234567K90` is also acceptable, as is `12345678901` - 11 digits, where `9` is matched by the dot.